# Monitoring Linux server processes

Tags: unix, monitoring, monitor, ps, unix-socket

This is for some suggestion and choice of right approach to monitor.

There is a RHEL6 server running several processes running under several SILOs and sandboxes, we need to monitor these process making sure these processes are up and running.

Currently I have made a script to which loops through all the sandboxes and check for the process status, then I send out a mail to the respective team with the list of jobs not running, as attachment.

**Problem:**
   Now since the number of sandboxes and jobs are quite many, it takes time to check and process and send out the mail, it sometimes leads to the outage for the other team.
  Also sub shell processes of the crashes when the server resources are low.

I am looking for an approach to make this monitoring quick and simple.

**My Thoughts**

The below command is quite handy and gives me the list of running processes.

```
    ps -ef|grep pset| awk '{print $9}'
```

***Result,e.g.:***

```
  /ab_sandbox_pi/propia/pset/process_a.pset
  /ab_sandbox_pi/apsia/pset/process_b.pset
  /ab_sandbox_pi/propia/pset/process_c.pset
  /ab_sandbox_pi/apsia/pset/process_d.pset
```

I want to use this command through a script and then process the resultant text.

1. The script would write to a specific sheet of a excel, say *sheet_pset*, this excel would have a predefined macro/vb code to act as a string processor , would fetch data from *sheet_pset* and show result(based on condition applied), may be by click of a button or drop down.
2. Creating a cient side java program, which would connect to RHEL6 server and get result of the ps command. Then at the client side would process and show the result.
   But this would require some authentication setup at RHEL6 which I am not sure would be fecilitated.

Please suggest which is the appropriate aprroach, or any other suitable approach I can take.

Comment: This doesn't sound very complicated so you could probably do it in a number of languages. I don't see the need for a java desktop app though - couldn't it just be browser-based? A few pages of php and a sqlite database, maybe? Anyway, the next guy seeing this will likely suggest his go-to language/db combo and I think it's impossible to say what's best.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you're looking for `supervisord`...

Comment: i cant install any db on this server..  permission issues...

Comment: i cant install any db on this server..  permission issues... the only language support i have is shell script,  python and java....  cant install supervisord even..  have limited support..  need a best and quock way to handle think...

Comment: Encrypt the lot and use dropbox via python or another server under your control as the middle man? Fetch and decrypt on the client

Comment: Consider the more correct and slightly more efficient `ps -e -o args= | awk '/ps[e]t/{print $2}'`.  More correct because the pattern matching command won't match itself in the process table (e.g., _`ps -ef | grep FOO`_ often matches the _grep_ process itself on its argument FOO).  More efficient because the pipeline is shorter (_grep_ and _awk_ can often be combined in common use) and because _ps_ outputs only what you care about.  Consider also moving to serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

### Solution is to do the data processing elsewhere - not on the server you try to monitor.

You should extract the whole `ps -ef` and send it to another server. Once you have retrieved the `ps` data to another computer, you do the filtering / table generating work.

- Either you do through ssh from another server (this would be the easiest, but not possible given your architecture, agreed),

  ```
  ssh  -o BatchMode=yes  usernam@servername " ps -ef "
  ```
- or you go on doing it by mail, but you only mail the complete extract to you --> you can send the whole thing *by mail* to **yourself**, and then have something processing the whole data on your computer, then send emails to everyone.

Comment: Good suggestions. *"(...) doing it by mail (...)"* Might as well add private/public key encryption while you're at it.

Comment: I mean, she already sends mails to everyone from the server.... so he should send only one mail.

Comment: I was thinking that we don't know if OP's server is using any form of transport layer encryption (HTTPS) to keep other people on the network from snooping on the out-going emails. Also, we don't know if OP trusts his/her email provider (I personally don't like sharing all my logs with google, for instance)

Comment: the network is secure,  so i can send mails is whole process extarct,  thanks @chomel,  even i am willing to do that  but my concern is processing at the receiving end, sending at another server to process is not possible,  we have only single server access, where all the process runs..

Comment: @J.Chomel Thanks for the points, even I am willing to send the complete extract by mail. My concern is processing for the end user, the end user are not much aware, so i need to deliver something readable and meaningful for them. Is it possible to write the `pe -ef` result in a specific sheet of an excel sheet?

Comment: Hi Nishant, not sure I understood your correct need. If you cannot send to another server to do the processing, maybe you can send the whole thing _by mail_ to **yourself**, and then have something processing the whole data on your computer, then send emails to everyone?